# How to read two big files and compare contents

Tags: php, fopen

What i'm trying to do is to read big file 5.6GB have approximately 600Million lines and the second is 16MB have 2M lines.

I want to check the duplicate lines in these two files.

```
$wordlist = array_unique(array_filter(file('small.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES)));
$duplicate = array();
if($file = fopen('big.txt', 'r')){
    while(!feof($file)){
        $lines = rtrim(fgets($file));
        if(in_array($lines, $wordlist)){
            echo $lines." : exists.\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

But this take forever to finish ( its been running from 6 hours and didn't finish yet :/ ).

My question is. Is there a better way to search in huge files fast?

Comment: Fast isn't one of PHP's qualities.

Comment: Perhaps you can speed up things by not using `in_array()`, instead use `$wordlist = array_flip($wordlist)` to turn the wordlist elements into array keys, and then check if the string is in the list with `isset()`. This should take advantage of the key hashing to speed up things.

Comment: You are doing `echo $lines." : exists.\n";` meaning you are outputting the result. It is better if you store those lines in an array, or store the line number and then you process the data. SECOND: If the small list is a dictionary, then you need to make sure they are sorted. If this is true... then I will write my own function to compare based on first letters. In your case, you take one line from the big file and you are traversing the 2M lines. I will find a way to optimize this... do you really need to traverse all those lines?

Comment: @Havenard, Hmmm! but what is the alternative? and Yess array_flip idea speed my app like 300%. Thank you <3

Comment: If you use C with fixed size buffers it will run as fast as your HD can read the file.

Comment: @Havenard Lol, Could you please give me some sources to start with?

Comment: After switching to `array_flip` as mentioned by @Havenard, you can replace `in_array` with `array_key_exists` which will quickly find if the item is in the array.

Comment: @jdigital That was the plan all along. `isset()` does the same thing, perhaps it's even faster because it's not a real function. `array_key_exists()` doesn't take parameters by reference which implies copying the strings and more delay.

Comment: @Elementary, Maaan, Thats mean i have to open the big file two million time!, In my working in files with php, i always opened the big file and then the smaller one that will save time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't need to call `array_filter()` or `array_unique()` if you are going to call `array_flip()` -- it will eliminate the duplicates for you because you can't have duplicate keys in the same level of an array.

Furthermore:

1. `array_unique()` is stated to be slower than `array_flip()` (and there are times when it is slower than two `array_flip()`s)
2. `array_filter()` has a bad reputation for killing falsey/empty/null/zero-ish data, so I will caution you not to use its default behavior.
3. `array_flip()` sets up the very speedy `isset()` check.  `isset()` will likely outperform `array_key_exists()` because `isset()` doesn't check for `null` values.
4. I am adding the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` flag to `file()` call so that your lookup array is potentially smaller.
5. Calling `rtrim()` of every line of your big file, may be causing some drag too.  Do you know if you have consistently identical newline characters on both files?  It would spare you six hundred millions calls of `rtrim()` if you can safely remove the `FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES` flag from the `file()` call.  Alternatively, if you *know* the newlines (e.g. `\n`? or `\r\n`?) that trail the big.txt lines, you can append specific newline(s) to the `$lookup` keys -- this means preparing the smaller file's data versus every line of the big file.

Untested Code:

```
$lookup = array_flip(file('small.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES));
if($file = fopen('big.txt', 'r')){
    while(!feof($file)){
        $line = rtrim(fgets($file));
        if (isset($lookup[$line])) {
            echo "$lines : exists.\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think

```
 $wordlist=array_flip(array_unique(array_filter(file('small.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))));
```

which you actually use in your code,slows it.It may be better to build the wordslist once and foverer yourself:

```
if($file1 = fopen('big.txt', 'r')){
    if($file = fopen('small.txt', 'r')){
        while(!feof($file)){
            $line=trim(fgets($file));
            if(!isset($wordlist[$line])&&!ctype_space($line)&&!empty($line)){
                $wordlist[$line]=0;
            }
        }
        fclose($file); 
    }
    while(!feof($file1)){
        $line1 = trim(fgets($file1));
        if(isset($wordlist[$line1]))
            $wordlist[$line1]++;            
    }
  fclose($file1); 
}
```

At this step the variable $wordlist contain the list of all lines in your small.txt file and the number of occurences of each line in your big.txt file .
You could use the array like that or filter it to remove null lines.You could also sort the array with uasort to know more about which lines occurs the most and which one occurs less and and you can  even go further in your analyze...

Comment: The `small.txt` is small and only read once at the beginning of the program, whatever performance difference the way you parse this file in particular has is inconsequential to the overall performance of the program.

Comment: however .Try to think about internal functionning of each native function .First `file` which do the same as i do to collect all lines,then `array_filter` which loop once again to filter the empty string,after `array unique`,which achieve copy and loop to find unique value,and finally `array_flip` which also loop through the array. Think about what we call time complexity and  memory usage...you can downvote this  as you want but PHP is a high level language and if you really know how C works you will understand or it doesn't matter... i just use one native function  fopen to achieve it...

Comment: @Havenard what you call small is as you said 2M lines and thus ~2M of entries in an array.Could you try to implement all these native functions yourself and   cogitate on the global time complexity and memory usage of this line ` $wordlist=array_flip(array_unique(array_filter(file('small.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES))));`...Let me know once finished.

Comment: It's not the same simply because you are writing in PHP loops and procedures those functions do internally in native code, you will never match their performance.

Comment: these functions as you said are written in C internally and the logic is the same in C and in PHP.An algorithm efficiency is judged independently of the language based on time complexity and memory usage.According to you do your suggestion use less memory than my suggestion...Also if you had only used one of those functions your speech will be acceptable but 4...

Comment: It's not that simple. The C code is compiled and heavily optimized for the architecture, it runs directly over the CPU, and so does the memory manager. PHP is interpreted, it doesn't run directly over the CPU and it isn't optimized, everything is executed exactly as written step by step and on top of that all data is wrapped in a way that can interface with the script environment, there's garbage collection and there's all the double checking inherent of every weak typed language. It's like every tiny task is multiplied 10 fold in complexity.

Comment: Ok Havenard let's suppose you are right.Could you please post an answer using only native functions and which kept all the advantages that my code provide?It will help us all.And i will learn more this way please...

Comment: You mean the simple fact that it doesn't create two arrays? There isn't one.

Comment: it didn't create two arrays.It return number of occurences of each line,it saves memory.Did you already read the PHP doc on  generators and what they said about the native `file` function? you should...

Comment: Well I'm commenting specifically about the first part of your code where you get rid of `file()` for no apparent reason.

Comment: i get rid of it to avoid flipping later,to avoid duplicate,to filter and to initialize lines occurences values and all this once and forever...

Comment: @Elementary Thanks for your time, using file() function isn't too bad, because of mickmackusa i have removed array_unique() and array_flip(), so its not a big deal. But again thanks for your time. :)

Comment: no worries.However did you plan to collect duplicate lines somewhere or you just need to output them on screen with echo?